# Python script in Colab keeps throwing error message: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python-3.x, indentation, google-colaboratory

I'm currently using Google Colab in order to take advantage of its free GPU.  I was trying to modify a code that I copy and pasted from machinelearningmaster.com.  However, whenever I try to add a new code line, for example "print("some words"), I get an indention error.

I have tried adding tabs or spaces before the print call but I still get the error.  for example:
space,space,print("some words")
tab, tab   ,print("some words")

I have also checked the colab editor settings, currently the indention width setting are set to two spaces.

The first three lines are part of the original code, the print statement is 
my addition.  I copy and pasted this directly from the colab editor.  In Colab all four lines are aligned.  As you can see here only the first three lines are aligned. I don't know what's going on.

```
                img_path = images_dir + filename
                ann_path = annotations_dir + image_id + '.xml'
                count=count+1
                            print("this is count: ", count)
```

I expected this to print the value of count, instead I get an error message telling me: 
        IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Is this this exact indentation? Why is `print` indented so far?

Comment: You're mixing the use of spaces and tabs for indentation.  All that can be said is "don't do that".

Comment: @Carcigenicate I copy and pasted this example directly from the colab editor.  I left it as is so everyone could see how it looks when dropped into another editor.

Comment: @jasonharper,  in the actual code every thing is aligned.  I have tried to delete all white space before the print statement and replace with tabs, when that didn't work I did it again using spaces.  In both cases I get the same error.

Comment: @Rice Man's solution is perfect, you can do this in Sublime text itself. Control/ Cmd + F -> *press TAB -> find all -> apply 2 or 4 spaces accordingly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, after much searching and frustration, I have an idea of what went wrong, but even better, a solution to fix it.

It appears that the Google Collaborator (Colab) editor does not have a way to set it for tabs "\t" versus space (space-bar entries).  From the settings tab on the cell you can set the width of the tab from 2 to 4, but these will be interpreted as 2 to 4 space-bar entries.  Usually, this isn't a problem.  However, if you're like me and you want to test out code from the web, or be lazy and just copy paste from your editor, problems can arise.

Here's how I fixed it.  Before pasting the copied code into Colab, first put it into notepad++.  Go to View> Show Symbols >Show All Characters, click on this, you should now be able so see all the characters in the code.  Find a tab, it will look like an arrow pointing to the right -->, right click and copy it.  Open Search> Find, open the Replace tab.  Depending on your version of notepad++ the tab you copied will automatically be entered and the replace will already be set to four spaces.  Hit "Replace all".  This will automatically replace all tabs with equivalent spaces.  Copy the code from notepad++ back to Colab.  Now there will be no more conflicts.

Comment: I really wish google colab fixed this. It's such a bloody pain.

Comment: @PyWalker2797, For real!  They've gone to great lengths to get us used to using it, and it's specifically made for data science.   Which is currently dominated by Python IMHO, and this particular problem is purely Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a simple find and replace tool will just work fine. I also came across this error recently in Colab and I went through @Rice Man solution. The only difference was I used Libre office writer instead of Notepad++. I also found [this tool](https://tabstospaces.com/) to be helpful. I am not proficient in using Colab but this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick fix that worked for me related to this question.

I was trying to run a python script in colab and faced this error though the line seems at an appropriate indentation in that script.
I checked with the `!cat filename.py` cmd, and found out that the actual indentation appears different than it is in the script (hence the error).
Taking that unindented line (according to the colab) at the start of the line and using space afterward fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rice Man for the key point...
the simplest way (without using any other app)is to copy the indentation of a line (with same indentation level) and paste to the first of a new line, then you can write or copy your custom code at that level

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I used [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_python_formatter.htm) website to fix the error.

Copy your code to the site, then click beautify button on top left. This will remove indention errors.

If you want to know where the indention error is coming from, use @Prachi answer.